# How to fill "null" values in Python? I have keyword null for a time series data how can I delete them?

Tags: python, pandas, null

I have data like below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRm59.png)

I want to delete those null using pandas or some other library.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried any code at all? Have you looked at pandas documentation? Have you googled this exact question?

Comment: `series.interpolate()` is probably what you want

Comment: @goalie1998, Yes I googled and what I am getting is dropna and dropping null values or dropping NaN. What I am specifically looking for is keyworld null deleting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `dropna` in pandas to achieve this.

```
new_data = data.dropna(axis = 0, how ='any')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking specifically within pandas, I suggest

```
# suppose you already have a DataFrame similar to this:
# import pandas as pd
# df = pd.DataFrame({'data': [1, None, 3, None, 5]})

# to remove null values, do:
# df.dropna(inplace=True)

# to impute null values, do:
# df.fillna(inplace=True)
```

[More pandas reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

Possibly worth noting is that `None` is "null" in python.